# Survival horror trapped manga about being stuck in a cube box

Tags: story-identification, manga

A bunch of people, mostly kids, are trapped in a white cubed room and they have to go from room to room and survive deadly traps that will kill them

A giant guy with a cube with a freaky smiley face for a head is hunting them.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this? Any idea how the kids got there? Do the people die, and if so, how graphically? (i.e. is this likely tagged as "gore"? Or more pure psychological?)

Comment: its solved and its gore but it is under psychological genra check it out its 30 ch right now

Comment: Don't forget to accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**リセット・ゲーム (*Reset Game*)** by Kanji Yoshikai.

Synopsis from [Anime Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/reset-game)

> When he woke up, he was in a white room with no exits and an oncoming red cube... why?! Who put him there? And for what reason? The person who suddenly appeared before them is he a friend or a foe? He doesn't even believe his own childhood friend.

From [the official site](https://resetgame.jp/) (Japanese), [the 6 characters](https://resetgame.jp/character/) look like high-school kids.

From [the story](https://resetgame.jp/story/), they are trapped in the white cubed room ...

[image]

and they have to go from room to room and survive deadly traps that will kill them.

[image]

A giant guy with a cube with a freaky smiley face for a head is hunting them.

[image]

---

The manga [*has* been licensed by Mangamo for the official English translation](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/books/story/2020-04-15/mangamo-digital-manga-subscription-service).

> The entirety of Mangamo’s curated library is officially licensed and professionally translated. Among titles seeing their first official English language release are “Dropkick my Devil,” “Akatsuki Babies,” “Reset Game” and “Daily Meteor Strike.”

[Ganma, the Japanese publisher site](https://ganma.jp/resetgame) (Japanese) also provides 5 free chapters to read.

---

Previously tried to google with `サバイバル　漫画　白いキューブ　罠` (survival manga white cube traps) without any matching results, but googling for `漫画　キューブ` (manga cube) directly matched the first result.