# Manga about a group of people locked in a white cube

Tags: story-identification, manga

A group of people are locked in a white cube, they have to survive in it, every day a small square in the cube is pushed out, in that bar there is food to survive until the If it is filled it will open a link with another cube, this is a Japanese manga

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   It seems that you may have left out some words after "until the;" you should [edit] this to fix that sentence.  Also, when and where did you read this?

Comment: I read it through an online website in 2017-2018 so I don't remember clearly

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Japanese black and white story

Comment: Possible dupe of [Survival horror trapped manga about being stuck in a cube box](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262969/survival-horror-trapped-manga-about-being-stuck-in-a-cube-box)

Comment: Not this one, the stories I'm looking for are mostly about finding food and surviving in the cube

Comment: What do you mean surviving? We're they being killed by something? What was the danger other than starvation? How big was the room? Did they have amnesia? Did they know how they got inside the room or did they wake up there not knowing what the hell was going on? Was there a main character or an ensemble of characters? Can you describe any of the characters?